# jsPDF with autotable plugin table does not obey right to left text direction from html element attribute values such as <html dir="rtl" lang="ar">

Tags: javascript, html, css, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Dears,

I have the below HTML page

```html
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
```

with this simple table

```html
<table id="my-table">

    <tr>
      <th>الشهر</th>
      <th>المدخرات</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>يناير</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>فبراير</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

using jsPDF with autotable plugin

```
function htmlToPDF() {
    const doc = new jsPDF({ filters: ['ASCIIHexEncode'] });

      doc.autoTable({
        html: '#my-table',
        theme: 'grid',
        styles: {
            font: 'Amiri',
            halign: 'right'
        },

      })

    doc.save('report.pdf');
}
```

even if I set the html direction to rtl which it shown above it still saves the file in ltr direction.

I tried to put the dir attribute in different HTML elements such as

```html
<HTML>
<body>
<div>
<table>
```

without success

any help will be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I found this:

```
doc.viewerPreferences({"Direction": "R2L"}, true);
```

but it didn't work either!

Answer (score 1):

I had to reverse the columns of the table in a cloned object using JQuery

```
var rtlTable = $('#html-table').clone();
rtlTable.find('tr').each(function () {
    var tds = $(this).children('td,th').get().reverse();
    $(this).append(tds);
});
```

Then I passed the html element to the autotable function

```
var pdf = new jsPDF();
pdf.autoTable({html: rtlTable.get()[0], styles: { halign: "left" });
pdf.save("reprt.pdf");
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that worked for me.

I used part of @user3723572 great solution + I added utf8 support for others who want to achieve the same goal as me.

My Goal was to create a table with hebrew letters(UTF-8) + RTL.
First of all i loaded the font i wanted(it is a must if you want to use doc.text() with utf8 letters).

Then i set jspdf to rtl + reverse all the columns in my table.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setFont("VarelaRound-Regular"); //hebrew font
doc.setFontType("normal");
doc.setR2L(true); //RTL 
var rtlTable = $('#table').clone(); // clone the required table 
rtlTable.find('tr').each(function () { //reverse the row's columns order
    var tds = $(this).children('td,th').get().reverse();
    $(this).append(tds);
});
 
doc.autoTable({
    html:rtlTable.get()[0],
    startY: 10,
    styles: {halign:'center',font: "VarelaRound-Regular",fontStyle:"normal",fontSize:6,cellPadding:{top: 1, right: 0.5, bottom: 1, left: 0.5}} 
 });
 doc.save("a4.pdf");
```

you can check how to set new font in here - https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF under Use of Unicode Characters / UTF-8:
section.

Comment: you save my life today (עשית לי את היום נשמה תודהה רבה)

Answer (score 0):

The method that I found.
Using React and no jQuery.

The format I used is suitable for a large (wide) table.

```
    const tableRef = useRef<HTMLTableElement>(null);

    const ReverseTable = () => {
        const rtlTable = tableRef.current?.cloneNode(true) as HTMLTableElement;

        if (rtlTable) {
            Array.from(rtlTable.querySelectorAll('tr')).forEach((tr) => {
                const tds = Array.from(tr.querySelectorAll('td, th')).reverse();
                tds.forEach((td) => tr.appendChild(td));
            });
        }

        const doc = new jsPDF({orientation: 'landscape', format: [297, 420]});
        doc.addFont('fonts/noto_sans_hebrew.ttf', 'NotoSansHebrew', 'normal');
        doc.setFont('NotoSansHebrew');
        doc.setLanguage('he');
        autoTable(doc, {
            html: rtlTable as HTMLTableElement,
            theme: 'grid',
            startY: 20,
            margin: { top: 10 },
            styles: {
                font: 'NotoSansHebrew',
                fontSize: 10,
                cellPadding: 2,
                lineWidth: 0.1,
                lineColor: [204, 204, 204],
                halign: "left"
            },
        })
        doc.save('fileName.pdf');
    }
```